# N + sou desu is acceptable

Tags: grammar

`kono kami ha yuki sou da` - is this correct?
I know that rashii and mitai can be used  ~ but that's beside the point.

Also,if 'sou da' can be used with 'N' - how do we differentiate 'seems like' with 'heard that' in the above case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by your example sentence ... but as you state there's two ~そう constructions.

These are normally called [伝聞]{でんぶん}, hearsay and [様態]{ようたい}, "seems like".

According to nearly all the sources I can find, you cannot place a noun before the  "seems like" 様態 one. And when you do so before the hearsay one, you need to put a だ.

> この[本]{ほん}は[仏教]{ぶっきょう}の[聖典]{せいてん}だそうです。

I hear that this book is a Buddhist scripture.

Now what's confusing to me (as a non-native speaker of Japanese) is what you mean by two of the words you've got there "kami" and "yuki" ... "yuki" could be either "snow" ([雪]{ゆき}) or a verb conjugation of iku　[行]{ゆ}き or a personal name.　"kami" could be either [神]{かみ} "god" , [髪]{かみ} hair or [紙]{かみ} paper or [上]{かみ}. So I'm not really sure what you intend to mean by the sentence. Do you mean to say "the sky looks like snow", "I heard the God is snow", "The god seems to be going"  ?